# Accessing variable of ArrayList inside class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, getter

The class `Task` is describing tasks for a business which includes the variables: date, description, total amount of hours the task will take to complete, and the owner of the task.

An `ArrayList` is created for all the tasks named *tasks*. The problem is that a task can have more than one owner, meaning that creating a variable called owner wont work, so what I've done is that I created another class called `TaskOwner` and implemented that class as an `ArrayList` named *taskOwner* inside the `Task` class.

Now to the problem: You are supposed to be able to list tasks by a specific owner: meaning that you need to compare owners to the name you enter on your keyboard.

The problem in this lies within these lines of code:

```
System.out.println("What name of owner do you want to list tasks for: ");
String nameOfOwner = keyboard.nextLine();

if (nameOfOwner.toLowerCase().equals(tasks.get(1).getTaskOwner().getName().toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println(tasks.get(1));
}
```

I can't seem to access the variable named *name* inside the class `TaskOwner`, even though I've created getters for everything that is needed, so does anyone know how I am supposed to be able to access this information?

The error message I get is:

> The method getName() is undefined for the type ArrayList

Comment: Why have a class called TaskOwner when you can simply place an `ArrayList<Owner>` variable inside of Task?

Answer (score 2):

`getTaskOwner` appears to return an object of type `ArrayList` and not `TaskOwner` (that's what the error message indicates). In other words, it returns a list of owners. To call the `getName()` method, you need to loop over this list, and call the method on each element corresponding to an instance of `TaskOwner`.

```
System.out.println("What name of owner do you want to list tasks for: ");
String nameOfOwner = keyboard.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
    List<TaskOwner> owners = tasks.get(i).getTaskOwner();
    for(TaskOwner owner : owners) {
       if (nameOfOwner.toLowerCase().equals(owner.getName().toLowerCase())) {
           System.out.println(tasks.get(i));
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this solved it thank you! I understood the problem in this that it returned the ArrayList and not the object itself, just didnt know how to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

This returns an ArrayList:

```
tasks.get(1).getTaskOwner();
```

So you will need to call array list methods on it such as `contains(...)`

```
if (tasks.get(1).getTaskOwner().contains(nameOfOwner.toLowerCase())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other answers, the problem is you are calling `getName()` on an `ArrayList<>` instead of an object inside the ArrayList. The correct way of doing this would be to loop over all the tasks and then for each task, loop over their owners. Here is a sample piece of code, assuming the owners name is stored in the variable `nameOfOwner`:

```
for(Task task: tasks) {
  for(TaskOwner owner: tasks.getTaskOwner) {
     if (nameOfOwner.toLowerCase().equals(owner.getName().toLowerCase())) {
         System.out.println(task);
         break;
     }
  }
}
```

If you have also overloaded the equals method in the class `TaskOwner` to do a string match for the owner's name, you could just use the `Arraylist.contains()` method. But then, you will need to create a `TaskOwner` object out of the user input.

If your intention is to do task and owner lookups, you should also consider using `HashMap`. This would give you a better performance than `ArrayList<>` for direct lookups.